# Accessing attributes of resource from context.xml in program

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way in java to access the values of the resource tag given in the context.xml from the program?

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Resource name="jdbc/EmployeeDB" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="dbusername" password="dbpassword"
            driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:HypersonicSQL:database"
            maxActive="8" maxIdle="4"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

I know that we can get the the datasource the following way:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)
  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/EmployeeDB");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
... use this connection to access the database ...
conn.close();
```

But is there a way to print the userName and password in the program that i give in the resource tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast it to actual implementation of the resource (print out the name with .getClass().getName()) and use the methods provided there. For example tomcat's BasicDataSource has getPassword getUser methods.